# Do JSON serialized strings require to be enclosed by []?

Tags: json

Is this a valid JSON serialized string?

```
{"name":"n", "address_line_1":"a1", "address_line_2":"",
 "town":"", "postal_code":"", "region":"", "phone_1":"", "phone_2":"",
 "fax":"", "email":"", "web":""}
```

I doubt if it shall be enclosed in a list `[]` even being just one record.

I am also not aware if a JSON string is an actual standard or there are several interpretations on what a JSON string can include.

Comment: Paste your string here: https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see that it is indeed valid JSON.

Comment: @pault very useful link. Both (including `[]` and not including them) are valid JSON objects

Comment: Your doubts have a simple answer: http://json.org

Comment: Any valid JSON value is allowed at the top level.